# Solutions of the following Ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soliton-theory

I am a master student in mathematical physics. I study soliton and traveling wave solutions of the differential equations.

Let's consider the following ODE:
$$Q^{\prime}(\xi)=ln(A)(\alpha+\beta Q(\xi)+\sigma Q^2(\xi))$$
where
$A \neq 0,1.$

In a book, the solutions of the ODE are given as follows: **(But, I don't understand how to derive it.)**

There are twelve solution cases w.r.t coefficients of ODE.
Any help would be appreciated.

**CASE I)** When $\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma<0$ and $\sigma \neq 0$, then
$$
\begin{array}{l}
Q_{1}(\xi)=-\frac{\beta}{2 \sigma}+\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{2 \sigma} \tan _{A}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{2} \xi\right) \\
Q_{2}(\xi)=-\frac{\beta}{2 \sigma}-\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{2 \sigma} \cot _{A}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{2} \xi\right) \\
Q_{3}(\xi)=-\frac{\beta}{2 \sigma}+\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{2 \sigma}\left(\tan _{A}\left(\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)} \xi\right) \pm \sqrt{p q} \sec _{A}\left(\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right) \xi}\right)\right) \\
Q_{4}(\xi)=-\frac{\beta}{2 \sigma}-\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{2 \sigma}\left(\cot _{A}\left(\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)} \xi\right) \pm \sqrt{p q} \csc _{A}\left(\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)} \xi\right)\right) \\
Q_{5}(\xi)=-\frac{\beta}{2 \sigma}+\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{4 \sigma}\left(\tan _{A}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha \sigma\right)}}{4} \xi\right)-\cot _{A}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-\left(\beta^{2}-4 \alpha\right) \sigma}}{4} \xi\right)\right)
\end{array}
$$

**CASE II:**

$\vdots$

**CASE XII:**
When $\beta=\lambda, \sigma=m \lambda(m \neq 0)$ and $\alpha=0,$ then
$$
Q_{37}(\xi)=\frac{p A^{\lambda \xi}}{q-m p A^{\lambda \xi}}
$$
where triangular functions are defined as
\begin{array}{l}
\sin _{A}(\xi)=\frac{p A^{i \xi}-q A^{-i \xi}}{2 i}, \quad \cos _{A}(\xi)=\frac{p A^{i \xi}+q A^{-i \xi}}{2} \\
\tan _{A}(\xi)=-i \frac{p A^{i \xi}-q A^{-i \xi}}{p A^{i \xi}+q A^{-i \xi}}, \quad \cot _{A}(\xi)=i \frac{p A^{i \xi}+q A^{-i \xi}}{p A^{i \xi}-q A^{-i \xi}} \\
\sec _{A}(\xi)=\frac{2}{p A^{i \xi}+q A^{-i \xi}}, \quad \csc _{A}(\xi)=\frac{2 i}{p A^{i \xi}-q A^{-i \xi}}
\end{array}
where $\xi$ is an independent variable, $p$ and $q$ are constants greater than zero and called deformation parameters.

Comment: Ricatti equation. From which book are  these solutions given? Richard Palais among others had worked on Soliton theory.that yield negative K surfaces including Breathers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$Q^{\prime}(\xi)=ln(A)(\alpha+\beta Q(\xi)+\sigma Q^2(\xi))$$
In order to simplify the typing, change of symbols :
$\begin{cases}
Q=y \\
\xi=x \\
\ln(A)\alpha=a \\
\ln(A)\beta=b \\
\ln(A)\sigma=c
\end{cases}$
$$y'(x)=a+by(x)+c\big(y(x)\big)^2$$
This is a Riccati ODE. The usual change of function to solve it is :
$$y(x)=\frac{-1}{c}\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$$
which leads to :
$$u''(x)-b\:u'(x)+a\:c\:u(x)=0$$
This is a second order linear ODE with constant coefficients. I suppose that you can continue.

Answer (score 3):

*May be (I hope) a way to explain the differents cases*

The equation is
$$y'=a+b y+c y^2$$ Switch variables to make
$$x'=\frac 1{a+b y+c y^2}=\frac 1{c(y-r)(y-s)}$$ whre $r$ and $s$  are the roots of the quadratic.
Use partial fraction decomposition
$$x'=\frac{1}{c (r-s)}\left(\frac{1}{y-r}-\frac{1}{y-s} \right)$$
$$c (r-s)x+k=\log \left(\frac{|y-r|}{|y-s|}\right)$$ Now, depending on the sign of $\Delta=b^2-4ac$, you have quite many possibilities?